# Add 2 or more UIViewController class to a Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a reusable UIViewController class which has a tableview in it, say Class T. I have a list of things in this to be displayed.

Now when I press on one of the cells I create a new instance (alloc init) of this class and push it to the navigation stack and display new data in the same class T.

The problem comes when I pop the controller it goes to the first instance if the same class but the tableview displays the data which was displayed in the second instance.

I am using an XIB for Class T and not storyboard and segues.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks,

[EDIT - I] Initializing

```
T *controller = [T alloc] initWithNibName:@"T" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animation:YES];
```

Comment: Can you plz show the code for initialisation for first and second class?

Comment: Are you using the same data source for both table views?

Comment: No not the same datasource. It comes from server infact. Yes but if I referesh than it works otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Can you show the code for the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {} function

Comment: I think your source of displaying data in tableview has the most updated value as you got in second view. That is why it is showing same data in first view too. are you using some global data model for keeping your app data ?

Comment: Simplistically, if the first view controller is showing the second view controller's table data then either it's the same table view (i.e. you haven't correctly created a separate table view object) or it's a different table view but linked to the same datasource.

Comment: I have not yet resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is clearly based on the missing update of the data used in the table view's `datasource`. I suggest that each controller gets its own object, array or fetched results controller. You can then do something like this:

```
T *controller = [T alloc] initWithNibName:@"T" bundle:nil];
controller.dataArray = ... // populate the data source
```

Alternatively, using the same `datasource`, you have to make sure to check what should be displayed. Maybe you can give your table view controller class a `type` property that gets checked when displaying the data cell.

```
if (self.type == HierarchyFirstLevel) {
   cell.textLabel.text = ... // populate for first level
}
else if (self.type == HierarchySecondLevel) {
   cell.textLabel.text = ... // something else
}
// etc.
```

Comment: I do not get this. If I am creating a totally new instance of that class I believe this should not happen. Is it that the class objects are all new but it won't create an instance of the xib ?

Comment: The class instance is separate from the source of your data. If you are using the same "data source" (e.g., a singleton) to inform your *instance's* `datasource`, which instance displays it becomes irrelevant.